# Thermodynamics: Solving for Entropy, Gibbs and Helmholtz

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, free-energy

> A reversible melting of $32.0\ \mathrm g$ of ice at $0\ \mathrm{^\circ C}$ and $1\ \mathrm{atm}$. Solve for $\Delta G, \Delta S_\text{universe}$, and $\Delta A$

I'm also given latent heat of fusion/vaporization, heat capacity at constant pressure, ($C_p$) and the densities of water and ice at the appropriate temperature and pressure,

Solving for $\Delta S_\text{universe}$

from equation sheet: $$\Delta S_\text{vap} = \frac {q_{p,\text{vap}}}{T_\mathrm b}$$ Which is for vaporization and I assume I can transform that into $$\Delta S_\text{melt}= \frac {q_{p,\text{fus}}}{T_\mathrm m}$$ 
So solving for $\Delta S_\text{system}$ I get
$$\Delta S_\text{system}=\Delta S_\text{melt}= \frac {q_{p,\text{fus}}}{T_\mathrm m}$$

But the question asked for $\Delta S_\text{universe}$ not $\Delta S_\text{system}$. I know that $$S_\text{universe}=S_\text{surroundings}+S_\text{system}$$, so $\Delta S_\text{universe}$ must be $$\Delta S_{universe}=\Delta S_\text{surroundings}+\Delta S_\text{system}$$ But I'm given no information on the surroundings. How can I solve this? Is it possible that the change in entropy in the surroundings constant such that $\Delta S_\text{universe}=\Delta S_\text{system}$?

Solving for $\Delta A$ $$A=U-TS$$
 $$\Delta A = \Delta U -T\Delta S_\text{sys}$$ 
$$\Delta A = (q-P\Delta V)  -T\Delta S_\text{sys}$$
$$\Delta A = (q-P[\rho_\text{water}m-\rho_\text{ice}m])-T\Delta S_\text{sys}$$

But I don't know how to solve $q$ for this problem. Additionally, I'm not sure if the ice melted completely, so perhaps the change in Volume is less that what I wrote in the equation.

Solving for $\Delta G$
$$\Delta G = \Delta H-T\Delta S_\text{sys}$$
$$\Delta G = \Delta U+P\Delta V-TS_\text{sys}$$
$$\Delta G = (q-P\Delta V)+P\Delta V-TS_\text{sys}$$
$$\Delta G = q-TS_\text{sys}$$

But same as before I don't know how to solve for $q$.

Comment: What are the initial and final thermodynamic equilibrium states of the system?

Comment: Um I know that S(universe) becomes maximum @ equilibrium. I guess gibbs would need to be negative because the melting happened spontaneously. I don't have much intuitive sense with Thermo.

Comment: $$q_{fus}=T_m\Delta S_{syst}$$What does that tell you about $\Delta G$?

Comment: dG is Zero?! But the melting is spontaneous! how did you get the equation you just wrote?! what kinds of situations can I say dG is zero?

Comment: Ya see, this is why  I asked you what the initial and final equilibrium states of the system are.  Let me give you a hint.  The initial state of the system 32 g of ice @ 0 C and 1 atm.  Now, please tell me what you understand the final equilibrium state of the system to be.

Comment: The final equilibrium state would be 32 g of liquid water @ 0 C and 1 ATM since the question describes the system as melting.

Comment: Excellent.  Now, since these are two thermodynamic equilibrium states, should the changes in G, S, and A depend on whether the path between the two states is reversible or irreversible?  That said, why do you feel that the transition between the two states would have to be spontaneous (i.e., irreversible)?

Comment: !!! I didn't know spontaneous implied irreversible. I had the idea that the phase change was spontaneous because it happened on it's own (which I admit, now that I consider it doesn't make any sense at all), given this, can I say that $\Delta G$ of all Reversible reactions is zero?

Comment: Let's keep focused on the problem at hand.  For the constant pressure transition being considered, the change in enthalpy is equal to the heat added.  So $\Delta H=T_m\Delta S$, and $\Delta G=\Delta H-T\Delta S = 0$.  The change in G between any two phase equilibrium states is zero.   Does this make sense now?   Algebraically, how is $\Delta A$ related to $\Delta G$?

Comment: $\Delta A=\Delta U-T\Delta S$ and $\Delta G = \Delta H-T\Delta S$ so $\Delta A = \Delta U +\Delta G - \Delta H $

Comment: From the definition of $\Delta H$, what is $(\Delta H-\Delta U)$?

Comment: $\Delta H = \Delta U - PV$ So $\Delta U- PV -\Delta U= PV$

Comment: I can't make sense of this, but, anyway, $$\Delta H=\Delta U+\Delta(PV)$$.  So $$\Delta A=\Delta G-\Delta (PV)$$For constant pressure, $$\Delta A=\Delta G-P\Delta V=-P\Delta V$$where $\Delta V$ is the difference in  volume between 32 g of liquid water and 32 g of water ice.

Comment: Thanks for your help Mr. Miller! I think i understand more now. In the original post I neglected to realize $T\Delta S = q$ If  had done that substitution then all my q's would have canceled out.